# How to create new record from jstree using json

Tags: javascript, json

I would like to create the record from the jstree using context menu.

Please help to resolve my issue:

My Code:

```
     contextmenu : {
                     "items" : function (node) {
                          return { 
                              "view" : {
                                  label: "View Record",
                                  action: function(obj) {
                                      window.open("/" + obj.attr("id"));
                                  }
                              },
                               "create" : {
                                  label: "Add New", 
                                    action: function() { 

                                      createNode(node);
                                  }

                              },
**<I have removed some code >**
       } 
    });


  function createNode(parent) {

var currentParentId = parent.attr("id");

          $j("#tree").jstree("create", $j("#"+currentParentId), "inside",  { "data" : "NewName","state" : "leaf","attr" : { "id" : true,"rel":"noChildren"}},null, true);            

      }
```

Node is created but in Salesforce no new record created so I would like to create new record and assign the id to newly created record.

FYI I have attached the image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Visualforce remoting, it'll be quite easy to write an Apex method that supports creation of a new object with the required parameters. You'll just need to add the remoting call inside your `createNode` method.

Docs: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_js_remoting.htm